# Remove all text after last occurence in file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a bunch of lines inside a text file that looks like this

```
STANGHOLMEN_BVP01_03_ME41_DELTAT_PV
STANGHOLMEN_TA02_TF01_FO_OP
STANGHOLMEN_VV01_PV01_SP2
STANGHOLMEN_VS01_GT11_EFFBEG_X1
```

I am trying to remove the text after the last occurrence of _

So this is how i try to make my text look

```
STANGHOLMEN_BVP01_03_ME41_DELTAT
STANGHOLMEN_TA02_TF01_FO
STANGHOLMEN_VV01_PV01
STANGHOLMEN_VS01_GT11_EFFBEG
```

its usually around 700 lines, Best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse the file line by line and add the content to a new file. To split the string you can use [rsplit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) with `maxsplit=1`.

```
>>> with open("f_in.txt") as f_in, open("f_out.txt","w") as f_out:
...     for line in f_in:
...             f_out.write(line.rsplit('_', maxsplit=1)[0])
...             f_out.write("\n")
```

Comment: Didn't see your response was posting using my mobile. Upvoted

Answer (score 0):

You can user `rfind()` (returning index of substring looking from right side in simple words) from standard library, it will be the simplest way, but not so reliable.

```
last_index = string.rfind("_")
```

Next you have to slice yours string

```
new_string = string[:index]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rsplit() and use the index[0] value.

For example if `txt = 'STANGHOLMEN_VS01_GT11_EFFBEG_X1`

`txt1 = txt.rsplit('_',1)[0]` will give you the values upto EFFBEG.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("f_in.txt") as f_in, open("f_out.txt","w") as f_out:
     for line in f_in:
             f_out.write(line.rsplit('_', maxsplit=1)[0])
             f_out.write("\n")
```

This worked, however now all my text is in a long line, before it was sorted in lines.